# open list on click on input and creating an array based on options choosen

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, tags

I have to do an input that, once clicked, it shows a list of options available and the user can choose multiple options. Once the option is choosen, it's added to an array and it's shown as a tag inside the input, just like the input to choose tags when you ask a question on Stack Overflow. Obviously I'd like remove the tags just like Stack Overflow. The multiple options are retrieved via an http request to the server.

P.S: the binding by "click" below is just for example. I don't know if it's correct or if I should change.

This is the HTML I thought to contain the input and the list when the user click on it:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="role" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Roles</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="text" id="role" name="role" class="form-control">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let role of roles">
        <div (click)="getRole()">{{role.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the JSON I get from http request and I'd like the array with the chosen tags to have the same structure:

```
[  
  {  
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
  }
  {  
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
  }
]
```

I'm using Angular 5.2.8 and Bootstrap 4.

So my questions are:

- What should the connected function do (function "click") to perform what I asked?
- Do I need to use JQuery or any other libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in using a library instead of creating it from scratch then, the below-mentioned libraries can help:

- [ng-select/ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select)
- [roolebo/ng2-select-compat](https://github.com/roolebo/ng2-select-compat)

Comment: Thank you. It's just what I was looking for. :D